# In android, background color of linear layout is not working

Tags: android, colors, background

I'm using the below xml for dialogue in android.
However the background only applies on ViewPager, does not apply on linearlayout under the view pager.  but that linearlayout is always white..

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/AA"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="560dp"
    android:background="#fcfcfc"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/BBB"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="333dp" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="85dp"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="18dp"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/dialog_page_mark"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="18dp"
                android:gravity="top|center_horizontal"
                android:orientation="horizontal" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/dialog_page_number"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:textSize="15dp"
                android:visibility="gone" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="67dp"
            android:gravity="end|center_vertical"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:paddingEnd="24dp" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/CCCC"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="36dp"
                android:focusable="true"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:minWidth="0dp"
                android:paddingStart="10dp"
                android:paddingEnd="10dp"
                android:textAllCaps="true"
                android:textSize="16dp" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

And, in the code, I call these codes,

```
    WindowManager.LayoutParams wm = new WindowManager.LayoutParams();
    wm.copyFrom(this.getWindow().getAttributes());
    wm.width = LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
    wm.height = LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
    getWindow().setAttributes(wm);
    getWindow().setBackgroundDrawableResource(R.color.FCFCFC);
```

Am I wrong??
R.color.FCFCFC = "#fcfcfc"
Why the backgound color setting is not working the linearlayout under ViewPager?? Help me... Please..

Comment: Try Adding It Again In The Linear Layout of the View Pager .

Comment: Same problem here.  Never seen this bug before.  But this is my first time using ViewPager.

Answer (score 1):

Assign an id for your LinearLayout

Using below code to get instance:

```
LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.yourLinearLayout);
```

Using below code to change background color:

```
ll.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.FCFCFC));
```